# Can I get gradle build to fail when there is version conflict between two dependencies when one of them doesn't have group specified

Tags: gradle

I am trying to figure out how to get gradle to fail a build on a version conflict between two dependencies when one of them doesn't have group specified.

For example I have a project that depends on jar from configured flat directory repository (for a vendor)

`compile ':guava:r09'`

and a transitive dependency that points to module retrieved from maven repository

`compile 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1'`

I understand that by design *failOnVersionConflict* resolution strategy will not raise a conflict for the above example. I cannot determine group name for jars in flat directory and hence would like to raise a conflict where developer can force one of the module accordingly. Thank you for taking the time to read by question.

**Update:**

Based on Ben's comment, I am attaching the code snippet used to raise custom conflict. But this is not helpful in my case since I cannot take advantage of force resolution strategy to resolve the conflict. I could exclude transitive dependencies or remove direct dependency altogether. Hopefully it is useful to someone else.

```
gradle.afterProject {
project.configurations.each { conf ->
    def map = new HashMap<String, List<Dependency>>()
    //println "\tConfiguration- ${project.name}:${conf.name}"
    conf.allDependencies.each { dep ->
        //println "\t\t${dep.group}:${dep.name}:${dep.version}"
        ArrayList<Dependency> dependencies = null
        if(map.containsKey(dep.name))
        {
            dependencies = map.get(dep.name)
        }
        else
        {
            dependencies = new ArrayList<>()
            map.put(dep.name, dependencies)
            dependencies.add(dep)
        }

        if(dep.group == null || dep.group.equals("unspecified"))
        {
            for(Dependency depInMap : dependencies) {

                if(depInMap.version == null && dep.version == null)
                    continue;

                if(depInMap.version != null && depInMap.version.equals(dep.version))
                    continue;

                throw new GradleException("Customized Conflict: A conflict was found in " +
                        "${project.name}:${conf.name} between the following modules:" +
                        "\n- ${dep.group}:${dep.name}:${dep.version}" +
                        "\n- ${depInMap.group}:${depInMap.name}:${depInMap.version}")

            }
        }

        dependencies.add(dep);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can script this yourself by inspecting the `project.dependencies` in an `afterEvaluate` block and throw a `GradleExecption` if you detect an invalid mapping. Alternatively take a look at [ComponentSelectionRules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ComponentSelectionRules.html) and [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html).

Comment: It seems from what I understood by reading ComponentSelectionRules, it would reject dependency based on its properties which is not what I am looking for. ResolutionStrategy will be used by developer to resolve the conflict which configuration needs to raise in the first place. afterEvaluate looks promising and I will give it a try.  Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution I came up with. Given below is code snippet for some one else who may have use for it. The code isn't neat but is functional. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
    private static boolean isGroupEmpty(DependencyResolveDetails details){
        if (details.requested.group == null) {
            return true;
        } else if (details.requested.group == "unspecified"){
            return true;
        } else if(details.requested.group.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    configurations.all {

        def dependencyMap = [:]
        def forcedModules = resolutionStrategy.forcedModules
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->

            def targetToUse = null
            for (forcedModule in forcedModules) {
                if(forcedModule.name == details.requested.name &&
                        (forcedModule.group ==  details.requested.group || isGroupEmpty(details))) {
                    targetToUse = "${forcedModule.group}:${forcedModule.name}:${forcedModule.version}"
                }
            }

            if(targetToUse != null) {
                println "Forcing: " + targetToUse
                details.useTarget targetToUse
            }
            else {
                if(dependencyMap.containsKey(details.requested.name)) {
                    DependencyResolveDetails prevDetails = dependencyMap.get(details.requested.name);

                    boolean groupMatches = false
                    if(isGroupEmpty(prevDetails) || isGroupEmpty(details) ||
                            prevDetails.requested.group == details.requested.group){
                        groupMatches = true
                    }

                    if(groupMatches)
                    {
                        boolean versionMatches = false
                        if(prevDetails.requested.version == details.requested.version) {
                            versionMatches = true
                        }

                        if(!versionMatches)
                        {
                            //If versions don't match throw an exception.
                            throw new GradleException("Custom Conflict: A conflict was found in " +
                                    "${project.name} between the following modules:" +
                                    "\n- ${prevDetails.requested.group}:${prevDetails.requested.name}:" +
                                    "${prevDetails.requested.version}" +
                                    "\n- ${details.requested.group}:${details.requested.name}:" +
                                    "${details.requested.version}")


                        }
                        else {
                            //Use either one (in this case I force the one with empty group)
                            DependencyResolveDetails repl
                            DependencyResolveDetails pref
                            if(isGroupEmpty(prevDetails)) {
                                pref = prevDetails
                                repl = details
                            }
                            else {
                                pref = details
                                repl = prevDetails

                                dependencyMap.put(details.requested.name, details)
                            }

                            repl.useTarget "unspecified:${pref.requested.name}:${pref.requested.version}"

                            println "Replacing module " +
                                    "\n - ${repl.requested.group}:${repl.requested.name}:${repl.requested.version}" +
                                    "\n with " +
                                    "\n - ${pref.requested.group}:${pref.requested.name}:${pref.requested.version} ."

                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dependencyMap.put(details.requested.name, details)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```